# Coffeescript: Unexpected '{' when I try to create an object literal of object literals

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, syntax, coffeescript

For this syntax:

```
  BASE_RUNNERS = {  basesLoaded:      { first: "manned",  second: "manned", third: "manned" },
                    firstAndSecond:   { first: "manned",  second: "manned", third: "empty"  },
                    firstAndThird:    { first: "manned",  second: "empty",  third: "manned" },
                    secondAndThird:   { first: "empty",   second: "manned", third: "manned" },
                    first:            { first: "manned",  second: "empty",  third: "empty"  },
                    second:           { first: "empty",   second: "manned", third: "empty"  },
                    third:            { first: "empty",   second: "empty",  third: "manned" },
                    empty:            { first: "empty",   second: "empty",  third: "empty"  }
                  }
```

I receive the error:

```
[stdin]:154:27: error: unexpected {
                          firstAndSecond:   { first: "manned",  second: "manned", third: "empty",   addedScore: 0 },
                          ^
```

Not sure why, it looks legal to me.

Comment: How are using the object `BASE_RUNNER`

Comment: That code is fine and produces no errors. Check for hidden "funny" Unicode characters however.

Comment: @Pointy While I think I know what you mean, can you elaborate in the event that the OP or Google viewers do not?

Comment: @BlackVegetable right :)  Sometimes, often when cutting/pasting out of a browser or other application, non-visible Unicode characters go along for the ride. You can't see them in the text editor (without explicitly asking; depends on the editor etc), but the JavaScript parser sees them and doesn't know what they are.

Comment: @MoazzamKhan Its part of a baseball simulation side project I'm working on. It represents all the possibile base runner combinations in a baseball game.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The braces are not the problem, the problem is the non-CoffeeScript indentation. CoffeeScript is very sensitive to whitespace, even when you supply the optional braces you still need to be careful that your indentation matches the desired block structure. The confusion goes away if you write it this way:

```
BASE_RUNNERS = {
  basesLoaded:      { first: "manned",  second: "manned", third: "manned" },
  firstAndSecond:   { first: "manned",  second: "manned", third: "empty"  },
  firstAndThird:    { first: "manned",  second: "empty",  third: "manned" },
  secondAndThird:   { first: "empty",   second: "manned", third: "manned" },
  first:            { first: "manned",  second: "empty",  third: "empty"  },
  second:           { first: "empty",   second: "manned", third: "empty"  },
  third:            { first: "empty",   second: "empty",  third: "manned" },
  empty:            { first: "empty",   second: "empty",  third: "empty"  }
}
```

The source of your difficulty was a non-indented `basesLoaded` combined with the indentation for the rest of the keys.

Answer (score 1):

Coffeescript doesn't accept the valid Javascript syntax, I had to rewrite it to this:

```
 BASE_RUNNERS =
      basesLoaded:    first: "manned", second: "manned", third: "manned"
      firstAndSecond: first: "manned", second: "manned", third: "empty"
      firstAndThird:  first: "manned", second: "empty", third: "manned"
      secondAndThird: first: "empty", second: "manned", third: "manned"
      first:          first: "manned", second: "empty", third: "empty"
      second:         first: "empty", second: "manned", third: "empty"
      third:          first: "empty", second: "empty", third: "manned"
      empty:          first: "empty", second: "empty", third: "empty"
```

which I'm not sure is better; looks a little worse IMHO.

Comment: It might be a little easier to read if indent them on the next line instead of keeping them all on the same line.

Comment: @rogMaHall That's true, but then it takes up a great deal of vertical space.

Comment: This one will work but I too prefer more braces for readability.

Comment: @rogMaHall My apologies for misreading the intent of your comment, I now see that you were hinting at the answer mu is too short was offering, and I agree that that version is a bit more readable